# Prove that $A \cup C \subseteq B \cup C$ iff $A \setminus C \subseteq B \setminus C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

This is an exercise from Velleman's "How To Prove It":

> 7. Suppose $A$, $B$, and $C$ are sets. Prove that $A \cup C \subseteq B \cup C$ iff $A \setminus C \subseteq B \setminus C$.

Proof: Suppose that $A \cup C \subseteq B \cup C$. Let $x \in A \setminus C$ be arbitrary. Then $x \in A$ and $x \notin C$. Suppose $x \notin B$. Since $x \notin B$ and $x \notin C$, $x \notin B \cup C$. Since $x \notin B \cup C$ and $A \cup C \subseteq B \cup C$, $x \notin A \cup C$. But this contradicts the fact that $x \in A$. Thus, $x \in B$. Since $x \in B$ and $x \notin C$, $x \in B \setminus C$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, it follows that $A \setminus C \subseteq B \setminus C$.

Now suppose that $A \setminus C \subseteq B \setminus C$. Let $x \in A \cup C$ be arbitrary. Then either $x \in A$ or $x \in C$. Suppose $ x \notin B \cup C$. Since $x \notin C$, it follows that $x \in A$, so $x \in A \setminus C$. Then since $A \setminus C \subseteq B \setminus C$, $x \in B \setminus C$. But this contradicts the fact that $x \notin B$. Thus, $x \in B \cup C$. $\square$

My first approach for the $\rightarrow$ direction was to use a proof by cases on whether $x \in B$ or $x \notin B$. If $x \in B$, then clearly $x \in B \setminus C$, but the other case leads to a contradiction (as shown in the proof above). In a proof by cases, is it valid to eliminate some cases by showing that they lead to a contradiction? I would appreciate any other comments on the proof as well. Thanks!

Comment: "In a proof by cases, is it valid to eliminate some cases by showing that they lead to a contradiction?"  Of course!  If something leads to an irrefutable result of course you can do it.

Comment: But you don't need to do a contradiction.  If $x \in A\cup C$ either $x\in A$ or $x \in C$.  If $x \in C$ then $x \in C\subset B\cup C$.  ANd if $x\not \in C$ then $x \in A$. But $x \not \in C$ so $x \in A\setminus C \subset B\setminus C \subset B \subset B\cup C$.  So in both cases you have i) $x \in A\cup C$ and $x \in C\implies x \in B\cup C$.  And ii) $x \in A\cup C$ and $x \not \in C\implies x \in B\cup C$.   So either way... $x\in A\cup C \implies x \in B\cup C$.  No need to find a contradiction.

Comment: ""In a proof by cases, is it valid to eliminate some cases by showing that they lead to a contradiction?"   A valid and correct result is a valid and correct result.  If you can get a valid and correct result be riding an elephant and doing a rain dance than you are allowed to ride an elephant and do a rain dance.

Comment: @fleablood Thank you! It makes much more sense to me to use cases on whether $x \in C$ or not. Could you please post this as an answer?

Comment: Math isn't modern dance or contact sports where we follow rules because they are the rules of the game.  We follow rules because they are valid and lead to logical conclusions.  If a case leads to a contradiction then that case can't be true and concluding that that case can never happen is an irrefutable result and we can't deny it. A coach can't come down and say "You can't do a subproof by condradiction in a proof by cases, and by the way you can't wear white after labor day". Our logic stands.  It's irrefutable. We don't need no stinkin' rules.

Comment: I'd rather not post my answer, as that would imply my proof is "better" than yours and that I have a "right" proof and you have a "wrong" proof.  Your proof is utterly correct.  And your concern that we might not be allowed to do a proof by contradiction within a proof by cases is not a concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can eliminate cases using contradiction,your proof writing is totally ok..

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple proof

\begin{aligned}
A\cup C&=(A\setminus C)\cup C\\
&\subset (B\setminus C)\cup C = B\cup C
\end{aligned}

The first line uses the fact that $A\cup C = (A\setminus C)\cup C$ which you can proof easily using "$x\in\,$"  type of arguments as in your proof. The rest of the arguments consists of rather simple observations:

- first line to second: we use the assumption $A\setminus C\subset B\setminus C$;
- second to third line: same arguments as in first line.